# How to get array from ajax call in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, node.js

My ajax call looks like this:

```
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET","/showChamps?textInput=" + searchChamp.value,true);
request.send(null);
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (request.status == 200 && request.readyState == 4) {
  //how do i get my array
}
```

};
}

I have sent an array from my node.js server but I don't know how to get that array because request.responseText does not give me back an array. Also it would be appreciated if the answer is in javascript.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: In what format is the "array" being communicated? If the server responds with JSON, you can use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to create the `Array` from the `responseText`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onload = function() { 
    if(xhr.status === 200) {
        var responseHTML = xhr.responseText,                 // HTML
            responseXML = xhr.responseXML,                   // XML
            responseObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);   // JSON
    } 
};
```